# Distiguishing mutant knots

Tags: rt.representation-theory, knot-theory

Can an invariant from a quantum Lie algebra ever distinguish mutant knots?
(Maybe if it is "chiral"...whatever that means :-)
(Note that Kauffman abstract tensors/skein equations CAN distinguish mutant knots -
[here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67048/now-that-i-got-a-mutant-discriminating-invariant) is my smallest example - and many of those *are* quantum Lie algebra invariants.
(A no to the above question would mean: not all of them are. Would be good to know.)