# "Higher" knot mutants

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory

[Mutation Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_(knot_theory)) [My related question 1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210069/distiguishing-mutant-knots) [My related question 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67048/now-that-i-got-a-mutant-discriminating-invariant)

[image: How to mutate]

Top: How wiki describes mutation. Doesn't generalize well.

Bottom: How I think of it.

Now replace "four" in the Wiki text by "six". Is anything known about such higher mutants? This could look e.g. like this:

[image: Generalization]

Endnote: This is IMHO still not the optimal framework to think about mutation. You need virtual crossings, and since they don't mix well with overcrossings - yikes, forbidden move - to work with the antisymmetric rank 4 tensor of the aforementioned Lie algebra.

[image: Mutation in style]

Then you can classify any tangle by symmetry under [the symmetric group $S_4$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S4) and find that mutation equality kills the modules of the two $d=3$ irreps. My dabblings with higher tangles suggest that, likewise, for the symmetric group $S_6$ only the five irreps marked in the pic below survive for a "decent" knot polynomial, and it would be interesting which "higher mutations" produce this result. But I ask that as a new question eventually, this was *very* shorthand...

[image: Allowed irreps]